# RSPEC - PUT request return error 405

Tags: api, testing, rspec, put

i have this test

```
describe 'PUT #start' do
  before do
    put :start, abtest_id: @variation.abtest.id.to_s,
                variation_id: @variation.id.to_s, format: 'json'
  end

  it "shoud return HTTP 200 status code" do
    expect(response.response_code).to eql(200)
  end
end
```

This is the response

```
Failure/Error: expect(response.response_code).to eql(200)

   expected: 200
        got: 405

   (compared using eql?)
```

I can't make put request with rspec. Someone would have an alternative to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

405 means 'Method Not Allowed', for example, the endpoint accepts POST requests but not PUT requests.

Without seeing the implementation, it's impossible to know whether the problem is in the spec or in the endpoint being tested.